# Handling API calls in Redux without no action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently doing some project using React+Redux.
I eagerly want you guy's help.

My situation is:

when I load another page, I want to handle API calls without any action.

but, when I load it, the token (information) that I gave at initial page is gone..

How do I handle API calls in Redux without any action when loading another page?

(redux update state without re-render? I don't even get the right keywords to ask.. sorry about that)

Comment: hello. welcome to stackoverflow. please check out the guidelines for asking questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . This particular question does not contain any specific details or a specific problem, which will make it hard to get help. I can suggest you create an example of what you are doing here https://codepen.io/, here https://plnkr.co/, or in stackoverflow https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support..... then people might be able to help

Comment: **token (information) that I gave at initial page is gone** where you setting the token. Do you update the state somehow with this?

Comment: I want to keep the token that I gave at initial state. I used ComponentDidMount and got the state. when I split the page and go to that page, the information that I gave is gone. I want to update the state, and this updated state should be applied at another page without any action.

Answer (score 0):

The question is kinda confusing, what is the diference when you load another page and when you load it?

You have an api call in a url that saves to redux something, and when you load another page, that doesnt trigger that same action in the previous url, you dont have that info in redux, is that the question?

If so you can just check if that redux value is avaiable and dispatch the action that populates it again. 
Does that action depends on any info avaible in the first page that doesnt exist in the new one?